# Show 2D buildings in Android Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am new to the java google maps API on Android and would like to display a ground overlay over buildings.

Unfortunately, buildings are by default shown in 3D, which gives an annoying look when you place a ground overlay above.

I have found this method in similar discussions:

`GoogleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(false);`

But as pointed out in those same discussions, it deletes buildings altogether without leaving their 2D base.
I still want to keep it, similarly to how the GoogleMaps website shows them.

Is this currently possible?